# Different UART port on rp2040

Tags: rust, embedded, uart, raspberry-pi-pico, rp2040

How do I configure non-standard UART pins on the Raspberry Pi Pico in a Rust project?

I'm following the Rust [rp2040-project-template](https://github.com/rp-rs/rp2040-project-template) and, using another Picoprobe, can see log messages in the terminal as the onboard LED blinks.  I gather it's possible to use different pins for UART TX & RX, but how is this configured in the context of the Rust project template?  My goal is to free up pins 1 & 2 for other purposes.

Section 4.1 of the official [getting started with pico guide](https://datasheets.raspberrypi.com/pico/getting-started-with-pico.pdf) implies there is a board configuration file, but it seems to be a [C header file](https://github.com/raspberrypi/pico-sdk/blob/master/src/boards/include/boards/pico.h) which I don't know how to use.

Comment: The configuration is specified by the [`rp-pico`](https://github.com/rp-rs/rp-hal-boards/blob/main/boards/rp-pico/src/lib.rs) dependency, so you would need to replace it with your own `rp-eletvon` crate that configures the pins the way you want them.

Comment: @Jmb, I see lots of aliases there, but can't see how UART settings are specified, or what I'd have to change in order for `defmt` to send logs to the other pins.

Comment: This was not clear from your question. In the template you gave, `defmt` outputs messages using RTT, i.e. through JTAG not the UART. So pins 1&2 should already be available for other uses…

Comment: @Jmb, looks like I don't understand.  I thought the probe gets the log messages from UART on pins 1 & 2, like in the diagram here https://reltech.substack.com/p/getting-started-with-rust-on-a-raspberry
Any tips on what to read to correct understanding would be appretiated.